# Filter two dataframe and shows the unmatched value as pandas table with values

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have two pandas tables named "Top product"  and another table "Dealer". I wanted to compare Dealers table with Top product table and print out Output table as shown in the **Table: Output** . Table Output content all the products that dealers in **Table: Dealers** don't have with the "Avg_amt column". I have tried this code but it does not work.

`cond = df_Dealer['product'].isin(Top_product['product']) df_dealer.drop(Top_product[cond].index, inplace = False)`

| postcode | product | Avg_amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | A | 3200 |
| 200 | B | 3070 |
| 200 | C | 190 |
| 201 | A | 490 |
| 201 | D | 210 |
| 201 | E | 4000 |

**Table : Top Product**

| postcode | dealers | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | X | A |
| 201 | K | B |

**Table: Dealers**

| postcode | dealers | product | Avg_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | X | B | 3070 |
| 200 | X | C | 190 |
| 201 | K | A | 490 |
| 201 | K | D | 210 |
| 201 | K | E | 4000 |

**Table : Output**

Comment: Why first row from top product table is not included in the output?

Comment: Yes same question

Comment: `Top_product.merge(df_Dealer,on='postcode',how='left')` ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge two tables on 'postocde' and select from the result all rows where values are different in column 'product'. Then we drop the column which does not need to be displayed in the output:

```
result = Top_product.merge(df_Dealer, how='left', 
                           on='postcode', suffixes('','_y'))

result.loc[result['product'] != result['product_y'], :]\
      .drop('product_y', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: the first row should not be included since it match with the top product table. The output is to display the product  that are in the top product but missing in dealers table

Comment: I got an error which is the name 'result' is not defined. can u show how to rectify this

Comment: Please try it now.